# Convert linq expression from method syntax to query syntax

Tags: linq, iqueryable

Well I've got a query

```
var grouped = from a in query
              group a.Payment by a.PaymentRecieverId
              into g
              select g;
```

`query` is a `IQueryable` of `new { Payment payment, int PaymentRecieverId }`

How can I convert this method expression to query?

Comment: What do yo mean by "convert this statement to expression"?

Comment: Actually what you have currently is a query syntax, so you seem to be looking for method syntax. That's pretty basic, take a look at [`GroupBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.groupby(v=vs.110).aspx) methods. Hint: `into g select g` is redundant.

Comment: Thanks for hint. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the question is how to map `group a.Payment` part.

The `GroupBy` method has several overloads, you need the [one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549270(v=vs.110).aspx) that allows you to specify `elementSelector`:

```
var grouped = query.GroupBy(a => a.PaymentRecieverId, a => a.Payment);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean lambda syntax, then it will be:

```
var grouped = query.GroupBy(x => x.PaymentRecieverId);
```

If you mean SQL query, then just hover your mouse on query object while debugging:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I mean lambda syntax. :)

Comment: Yet, query.GroupBy(x => x.PaymentRecieverId) is analog for "group a by a.PaymentRecieverId" not "group a.Payment by a.PaymentRecieverId" isn't it?